# NodeJS / iOS - How to get a returned value from a binary after calling it with HTTP POST

Tags: c++, ios, node.js, afnetworking

I have an iOS app (Objective C) and this app call some C++ binaries using NodeJs.

So far, I have been able to execute remotely my C++ program from a clicked button on my app using HTTP POST with the library AFNetworking 3.

iOS App --> Button clicked --> HTTP POST --> Node JS call --> C++ program call (this latter return true or false)

Now, I would like to get the value (True or False) returned by my program. How can I do that ?

I have already used the GET method to get a file on my server but I don't know if it's appropriate to use it for this case i.e get the returned result of my program.

Do you have an idea how can I achieve this ?

Thank

Comment: HTTP requests have responses. What do you think they're for if not this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to retrieve the value returned by your C++ program, you need first to retrieve the returned result from NodeJS.

Assuming you are using `ExpressJS` as your HTTP server, you should implement your endpoint with something like:

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/endpoint', function (req, res) {
    const child = execFile('my_exe', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).send('False')
    } else {

        if (stdout === 'True') {
            res.status(200).send('True')
        } else {
            res.status(500).send('False')
        }
    }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

If the call succeeded, the server will respond `True` with the status 200 and if it fails, it will return `False`with a status `False`.

Now, in your call to the server from the iOS application, you can use Alamofire like:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"someURL" parameters:@{} error:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        /* Network error*/
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
            case 200:
                NSLog(@"Success")
                /* Code in case of success == Server returned True  */
            default:
            /* Code in case of no success  == Server returned False */
                NSLog(@"Error");
        }

    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: Works perflectly. Thank you ! I have a better understanding of this now. However, I had to add manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]; otherwise it throws an exception when the server wants to get the response. "Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"